# how to Handle " " On Inputtex in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<html>
<form action="index.jsp">
    <body>
        First INPUT:
        <input name="firstinput" type="text" name="fname">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <%
            String first = request.getParameter("firstinput");
            out.println(first);
        %>
    </body>
</form>
</html>
```

This is my code when enter `Hello` then it print `Hello` and when enter `"Hello"`, then it prints `"Hello"`. In the later case, I want it should print `Hello`. How I will do this? Please tell me How I can remove `"`, if a user enters a quoted text?

Comment: Handle it in javascript.Dont allow user to enter "" quote

Comment: User can put But it should display hello if user will input"hello"

Comment: first.replace("\"", " ");

Comment: use proper capitalization and grammar, it helps people to easily interpret the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with this,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<html>
<form action="index.jsp">
    <body>
        First INPUT:
        <input name="firstinput" type="text" name="fname">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <%
           String first = request.getParameter("firstinput");
           if(first!=null){

              String data=null;
              if(first.startsWith("\"") && first.endsWith("\"")){
                data = first.substring(1, first.length-1)
              }
              out.println(data );
         }

        %>
    </body>
</form>
</html>
```

do proper null check if i missed any.

Comment: While it is right and necessary to validate/clean input at server side. A good practice is to validate the input on client side as well. It brings good usability to the software.

Comment: I agree, I just wrote how he needs. If we look at that sense, then generally it is not a good practice to write Scriptlet inside JSP as it should be used for View and only to iterate List for filling table etc. So looking at his sample I thought he is just trying sample, so did I mentioned solution. better way is what you suggested.

Comment: But when enter \hello\ then also we need to display Tex format only hello ' hello ' in htis case also i want if user will take input with special charcater then it should remove

Comment: @Anil: I just gave an example, you don't need to copy paste simply, change the condition inside based on your business scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one

```
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...


<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<c:out value='${fn:replace(param.firstinput, "\"", " ")}'>
     no parameter 
</c:out>
```